# Interacting with a flash application using python

Tags: python, flash, testing, automated-tests, jython

I'm contemplating using python for some functional testing of flash ad-units for work. Currently, we have an ad (in flash) that has N locations (can be defined as x,y) that need to be 'clicked'. I'd like to use python, but I know Java will do this.

I also considered Jython + Sikuli, but wanted to know if there is a python only library or tool to do this. I'd prefer to not run Jython + Sikuli if there is a *native* python option.

TIA.

@user1929959 From the pyswftools page, "At the moment, the library can be used in Python applications (including WebBased applications) to generate Flash animations on the fly.". And from the bottle-flash page, "This plugin enables flash messages in bottle.". Neither help me, unless I'm overlooking something ...

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways I've seen around the net, but most seem to involve exposing Flash through JS and then using the JS interface, which is a bit of a problem if you are trying to test things that you don't have dev access to, or need to be in a prod-like state for your tests.  Of course, even if you do that, you aren't really simulating user interaction, since you are working through an API.

If you can reliably model your Flash components with fixed pixel positions relative to the page element the Flash component is running in, you should be able to use Selenium Webdriver to position the mouse cursor and send click commands without actually cracking Flash itself.  I'm not 100% sure that would work, but it seems at least worth a shot.  Validation will be a bit trickier, but I think you should be able to do it with some form of image comparison.  A few of the Flash automators I saw are actually using image processing under the hood to control both input and output, so it seems like a legitimate way to interact with it.

Comment: I've used Selenium in the past (w/Java) and the IDE (javascript). The nice part about this is our ad fire events (request) which I'll be hooking into later ... so the validation doesn't need to happen in flash at the time of the click, I'll be comparing my known click w/the click data recorded in our DB from the event. So the take-away is there is not really a 'standard' way to do this in python, but just telling python coordinates and having it click the flash unit. I'll consider your suggestion about Selenium Webdriver, thanks.